# Can't get holidays from Google calendar

Tags: ios, object, calendar, synchronization

I am create calendar by get events from Google Calendar. I can get and sync events i created on app or on google calendar (the same account). But i cant get list holidays from Google Calendar, it always notifice error.

`NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/vi.vietnamese#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com?key=AIzaSyBR0P4iIZZOtEhAjSBOgQYLR0EP5YQi0hY&access_token=ya29.aAHV_2tZKqB_KIIeBMYHttUzvGX5XRcpFillQOVZLwDxiADhRphydHwLv6EO2Nit6i2RhFtZPN5ZdA, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unauthorized (401)`

Comment: The error so clear: unauthorized (401)

Comment: Please tell me more. i tried it many times but it error.